# Need to search multiple words in multiple table and display only those rows which has all the words in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, search, eloquent

I have an equipment which has type, manufacturer , model etc and it has attributes which are in other tables. I have created a join condition to connect with attributes. Now, if i search for a keyword related to type, manufacturer or model, then it shows correct result. But , i also need to search by attribute. I don't know how to extend this search so that it can also fetch result on the basis of attributes which are in other tables. Another thing is if i right both manufacturer and attribute in search box in one time , then i need result of equipments which has both manufacturer and attribute. Please advise. Any help would be appreciated
Currently my code looks like this:

```php
public function filterEquipementRecords(Request $request)
    {

        $equipements = Equipment::with('equip_status','equip_type','manufacturer', 'equip_model', 'equip_images', 'customer')

//These are join with different attribute tables
        ->selectRaw('equipment.*, Fuel.EQATTRPVAL_Value AS EQUIP_Fuel, Cab.EQATTRPVAL_Value AS EQUIP_Cab, Drive.EQATTRPVAL_Value AS EQUIP_Engine, PowerManu.EQATTRPVAL_Value AS EQUIP_Power, CabAttrib.EQATTR_YesNo AS EQUIP_CabYesNo')

        // Fuel Type

        ->leftJoin('equipattributetypes as FuelType', function($join) {
          $join->on('equipment.EQTYPE_ID', '=', 'FuelType.EQTYPE_ID')
          ->whereRaw("FuelType.EQATTRTYPE_Name = 'Fuel Type'");
        })
        ->leftJoin('equipattributes as FuelAttrib', function($join) {
          $join->on('equipment.EQUIP_ID', '=', 'FuelAttrib.EQUIP_ID')
          ->on('FuelType.EQATTRTYPE_ID', '=', 'FuelAttrib.EQATTRTYPE_ID');
        })
        ->leftJoin('equipattributepickvalues as Fuel', function($join) {
          $join->on('FuelAttrib.EQATTRPVAL_ID', '=', 'Fuel.EQATTRPVAL_ID');
        })

        // Cab

        ->leftJoin('equipattributetypes as CabType', function($join) {
          $join->on('equipment.EQTYPE_ID', '=', 'CabType.EQTYPE_ID')
          ->whereRaw("CabType.EQATTRTYPE_Name = 'Cab'");
        })
        ->leftJoin('equipattributes as CabAttrib', function($join) {
          $join->on('equipment.EQUIP_ID', '=', 'CabAttrib.EQUIP_ID')
          ->on('CabType.EQATTRTYPE_ID', '=', 'CabAttrib.EQATTRTYPE_ID');
        })
        ->leftJoin('equipattributepickvalues as Cab', function($join) {
          $join->on('CabAttrib.EQATTRPVAL_ID', '=', 'Cab.EQATTRPVAL_ID');
        })

        // Drive

        ->leftJoin('equipattributetypes as DriveType', function($join) {
          $join->on('equipment.EQTYPE_ID', '=', 'DriveType.EQTYPE_ID')
          ->whereRaw("DriveType.EQATTRTYPE_Name = 'Drive'");
        })
        ->leftJoin('equipattributes as DriveAttrib', function($join) {
          $join->on('equipment.EQUIP_ID', '=', 'DriveAttrib.EQUIP_ID')
          ->on('DriveType.EQATTRTYPE_ID', '=', 'DriveAttrib.EQATTRTYPE_ID');
        })
        ->leftJoin('equipattributepickvalues as Drive', function($join) {
          $join->on('DriveAttrib.EQATTRPVAL_ID', '=', 'Drive.EQATTRPVAL_ID');
        })

        //Power Manu

        ->leftJoin('equipattributetypes as PowerManuType', function($join) {
          $join->on('equipment.EQTYPE_ID', '=', 'PowerManuType.EQTYPE_ID')
          ->whereRaw("PowerManuType.EQATTRTYPE_Name = 'Power Manu'");
        })
        ->leftJoin('equipattributes as PowerManuAttrib', function($join) {
          $join->on('equipment.EQUIP_ID', '=', 'PowerManuAttrib.EQUIP_ID')
          ->on('PowerManuType.EQATTRTYPE_ID', '=', 'PowerManuAttrib.EQATTRTYPE_ID');
        })
        ->leftJoin('equipattributepickvalues as PowerManu', function($join) {
          $join->on('PowerManuAttrib.EQATTRPVAL_ID', '=', 'PowerManu.EQATTRPVAL_ID');
        })

// This is my query where i am searching on the basis of keyword, here i want to add attribute (which are there with joins) search also

            ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                if($this->quick_search_enable){
                    if ($request->quick_search != "") {

                        $query->where('equipment.EQUIP_ID', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('EQUIP_AddedOn', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('EQUIP_Year', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('EQUIP_VendorYear', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('EQUIP_Cost', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('EQUIP_Price', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('EQUIP_EmailPrice', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('EQUIP_Size', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('EQUIP_Hours', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('EQUIP_SerialNumber', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('EQUIP_VendorEquipNumber', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('EQUIP_Length', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%')

                   // These are relations in equipment model     
                            $query->orWhereHas('manufacturer', function ($query) use ($term) {
                                $query->where('MANU_ShortName', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
                            });
                            $query->orWhereHas('equip_type', function ($query) use ($term) {
                                $query->where('EQTYPE_Desc', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
                            });
                            $query->orWhereHas('equip_model', function ($query) use ($term) {   
                                $query->where('EQMODEL_ModelNumber', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
                            });

                        $query->orWhereHas('equip_status', function ($query) use ($request) {
                            $query->where('EQSTATUS_Name', 'like', '%' . $request->quick_search . '%');
                        });

                    }


                }
            });
```

Comment: From here ,my quick searching start,                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                
           ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            if($this->quick_search_enable){
                if ($request->quick_search != "") {

Comment: First thing if you are having relationships then why are you joining ?

Comment: As far as i know, No one may answer this type of question, to read a bunch of query code. it's time consuming for developers.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AkhtarMunir i updated my question. If you have any query please ask

Comment: @Makdous i updated my question. If you have any query please ask